# Excel question: I need a macro to assign a name to a picture based on the contents of a cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to copy a cell range and paste into another worksheet as a picture. I have tried recording a macro to achieve this task but when I run the macro I get the following message:
Runtime error: 1004 Unable to get the paste property of the picture class.
Here is my code:

```
enter code here

Sub MoveToSched()

MoveToSched Macro


    Range("F18").Select`

    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 85")).Select
    Sheets("Tag Maker").Select
    Range("D4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet Schedule").Select
    Range("J12").Select
    End Sub
```

I would also like to have any new pictures copied from this cell "F18" to go through the same macro. Any suggestions on how I can overcome the error message?

Comment: Where do you do the copying? Is this as recorded by the macro?

Comment: Yes I copy cell F18 from the active worksheet and the whole above code is as recorded by the macro. When done manually as recorded by the macro there is no error message. The error only occurs when trying to run the recorded macro.